# Modify value in a config file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a **config.py** file with parameters defined as

```python
class A:
   path='/a/b/c'
   ...

class B:
   path='/d/e/f'
   ...
```

I am trying to modify parameter `path` in `class A` in `config.py` using `sed -i` from a Bash script:

> sed -i <*script to replace path value with /x/y/z/ in class A*> config.py

expected result:

```python
class A:
    path= '/x/y/z'
    ...

class B:
    path= '/d/e/f'
    ...
```

I worked out how to *print* the value of path variable using this:

```
sed -i '/A/,/path/p' config.py
```

How can I replace the value though?

Comment: What's your actual question? The apparent but perhaps superficial problem is that you can't use shell variables inside single quotes.

Comment: @tripleee: I am new to shell scripting may be I am wrong. can you please let me know the solution of problem in correct way?

Comment: If I understood what you are asking, I could try, but you need to explain what your actual question is.

Comment: problem is I need to replace path value to '/x/y/z' from '/a/b/c' under class A which is written in a file

Comment: For the record, I posted a meta question to get this more broadly reviewed; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384487/should-this-previously-unclear-but-improved-question-be-reopened

Comment: In this particular case it may be better to use a real Python parser instead of sed, unless you can be absolutely sure that the file will be extremely simple.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of that one @Cerbrus. Completely different answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This sed solution solves your problem:<sup>1</sup>

```bash
sed -i "
  /class A/,/path/ {
    s!path=.*!path='/x/y/z'!
  }
  " config.py
```

Or if you want it all on one line:

```
sed -i "/class A/,/path/{s!path=.*!path='/x/y/z'!}" config.py
```

Further explanation:

- I search within the range `/class A/,/path/` and then within that range call the `s///` substitution.
- Note use of `!` as an alternate delimiter in the `s///` command.

<sup>1</sup> Tested using GNU sed on Mac OS X.